# create variable and add to array in same line

Tags: swift

I have created a bunch of views and sliders in my page and as a result I have quite a few constraint constants. My friend noticed that after each group I would use

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([...,...,...])
```

and then for the next set of items I would do the same.
He suggested that I just create an array like this

```
var allConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
```

and append each constraint to the array and then do it all at once

so after each constant that I create I am saying

```
allConstraints.append(...)
```

What I am curious to know is when I create the NSLayoutConstraint constant can I, in the same line, automatically add it to allConstraints array?

That seems like it would be cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doing so will make your code hard to read so i suggest you don't! but yes you can achieve this in a single line

```
allConstraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: AnyObject>, attribute: <NSLayoutAttribute>, relatedBy: <NSLayoutRelation>, toItem: <AnyObject?>, attribute: <NSLayoutAttribute>, multiplier: <CGFloat>, constant: <CGFloat>))
```

Comment: Do you recommend just saying....... allConstraints+=[xxx,yyy]....at the bottom of all of them?

Comment: e.g you have two constraints,

`let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()

allConstraints.append(contentsOf: [heightConstraint, widthConstraint])`